# X-AIR Edit App not working - UbuntuStudio 19.10

Tags: 19.10

Please help. I'm currently using UbuntuStudio 19.10. I'm using an app called X-AIR Edit from Behringer. This app is used to control XR18 digital mixer. It was working previously but as of recently the app's buttons and settings are no longer working after launching. I downloaded the app from the official Behringer site https://downloads.music-group.com/software/behringer/XAIR/X-AIR-Edit_LINUX_X64_V1.5.tar.gz

https://www.behringer.com/Categories/Behringer/Mixers/Digital/XR18/p/P0BI8/Downloads#googtrans(en|en)

Answer (score 1):

I am currently having the same issue on Manjaro.

But I have switched to another VT. I started the program with the following command(I was on TTY5):

```
xinit ./X-AIR-EDIT -- :1 vt5
```

It started, and I was able to move faders, click mutes, etc.
I am not sure what does this prove though. Is this something XFCE related?

Comment: I managed to kinda crash xfwm4 with
"xfwm4 --replace".
Now it's terrible but if I start X-AIR-EDIT, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I have an interesting observation.

With me it also does not work out of the box, but when reversing the button settings for my mouse to lefthanded in the control panel I can operate the the XAIR sliders and buttons.

Then it gets a bit awkward for the other applications, but I can control the mixer.

So it seems that the mouse buttons somehow get mixed up
.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Windows Focus was set to Hover. Fixed using Tweaks:

Windows > Windows Focus > Click to Focus